# What's the name of the connector on the DC Motor with Encoder linked below?

Tags: dc-motor, connector

What is the name of the connector on [this DC Motor](https://www.superdroidrobots.com/store/robot-parts/electrical-parts/encoders-accessories/encoder-motors/product=1099)?

I am trying to do a better job managing wires on my next robot project, and I am thinking of using some PCB's, so I would like to find the male version of these pins.

What's the name of this connector?

[image]

Comment: Tip: your question will be useless when the link dies. Add a picture into your post to avoid this.

Comment: It's right there on the third page of data.

Answer (score 1):

The housing is a [JST PHR-6](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_2&s=PH%20%2B%20PH%20PHN%20(crimp)) (my site).

https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/index.php?series=199

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/PHR-4/608606

[image: JST PHR-6]

{Digikey}

The crimp female contacts are sold separately.

> would like to find the male version

JST PH PCB headers, 6 positions: https://digikey.com/short/3fmhfnvm

Comment: thanks Davide.  I have the 32 series, which means my connector is the  JST PHR 6

Comment: I didn't realize what those letters meant until I started looking at amazon for connector types just now :(